# Why does Balsamiq talk about mockups when it doesn't seem a mockup

Tags: usability, wireframe

I have read about the difference between a mockup and a wireframe and it states that a wireframe is like a blueprint of how an application should be built while a mockup is a more visually detailed version of the wireframe, of how the application will look like. 
 I don't really understand then why Balsamiq talks about mockups when these mockups in balsamiq seem to me nothing but visually advanced. They seem to be a step before wire framing, a way to quickly put hand drawn elements on a page to represent a basic view of what groups of info the application holds. 
I'm not sure what i should start with, a mockup or a wireframe.

thx

Comment: Who defined the terms in the way you use them now? And why exactly do you expect Balsamiq to be bound to that exact definition?

Comment: http://blog.thelibzter.com/designing-a-website-wireframes-and-mockups. I'm not suggesting anything should be bound by something, i'm just trying to figure out how i communicate with customers what i'll be providing them with. I'm willing to use Balsamiq but i'm wondering what a mockup actually is. In Balsamiq it doesn't seem to be what the explanation states

Comment: Balsamiq lets you create complete wireframes by using links from one Balsamiq file to another to simulate the flows.

Answer (score 1):

I expect that they refer to them as "mockups" because there is the option to [make the wireframes interactive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_8IyyvECYrg).

The "hand drawn" look of the Balsamiq elements, and a lot of wire frames in general, has a purpose. Many people consider that it is better to start with wire frames rather than a full mockup including styles and graphics.

- It helps convey that the designs aren't yet final, making the client more open to suggesting changes.
- It allows the client to focus on functionality and navigation, rather than getting distracted / caught up in discussing cosmetic issues such as icons, color, font choice,  or graphics.

The sketchy look is supposed help emphasise this, however [not everyone agrees](http://www.silverspider.com/2010/sketchy-wireframes-the-comic-sans-of-ux/).

*FYI: You can switch off the sketchy look in Balsamiq, and just have a wireframe with straight lines.*

Comment: Ok thanks Franchesca, so actually Balsamiq is a wireframing tool as well. Maybe i'm mistaking those sketchy wireframes for mockups.

Answer (score 1):

'wireframe' and 'mockup' and 'demo' and 'prototype' aren't words with definitions that have clear boundaries. As such, there is no universally agreed upon set of definitions for them.

Frustratingly, there often isn't even an agreed upon set of definitions for them *within one organization*.

As such, a tool such as Balsamiq or Axure can actually end up creating any of the above types of documents depending on how the tool is being used and the particular definitions being used at any given time.

Answer (score -1):

The name, "Balsamiq Mockups," is misleading. Balsamiq is a wireframing tool. It lets you quickly show the client where elements will go on a site. True mockups demo how the finished site will look. Mockups include typography choices and color schemes while wireframes do not. Sometimes mockups are produced in Photoshop or Illustrator and sometimes they're made in HTML. I've used both approaches depending on the client, the project, and the timeline.

Usually we start with a wireframe and then produce mockups. Mockups take longer because the designer needs to pick color schemes, fonts, and images while wireframes don't commit to those elements.